# How can I bind boxview height in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I´m trying to draw something like a small bar chart using boxview control inside a listview (template with columns). So in one column of each item I want to draw the boxview with variable height (depending on a variable value)

Something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="75">
                      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                              <DataTemplate>

                                 <ViewCell >
                                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Label Text="{Binding Local}"  VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="10" TextColor="Navy" />
                                            <Label Text="Empate" Grid.Row="0" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="10" TextColor="Navy"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Visitante}" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" FontSize="10" TextColor="Navy"/>
                                            **<BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" HeightRequest="{Binding PctLocal}" WidthRequest="15"/>;**
                                            <Label Text="{Binding PctEmpate}" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="10" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding PctVisitante}" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="10" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding LocalSupporters}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="10" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding DrawSupporters}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="10" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding AwaySupporters}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="10" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                              </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I get an exception:

Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'.

Comment: What value are you trying to bind?  Are you sure it's not a problem with your XAML?

Comment: I think so, I replaced that boxview line with a simple label just to show the value of that binded property "PctLocal" and it´s displayed correctly. So the rest of xaml code works, except for that particular line.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure about this, but your problem might be related to the fact that you're trying to bind a string to a property of type double ([HeightRequest docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.HeightRequest/)). Try binding a double

Comment: Just did another test, replacing binding by a static height value and get the same error, seems that you are right issue is somewhere else

Comment: one of debugging tips is to comment some code section and see if the error still happens. If the error is still there, comment other part of code section.

Comment: Is the issue your semi-colon at the end of your BoxView, or just a typo?

`...WidthRequest="15"/>;`